# How to fix the output of the server to make it display the messages from the client correctly?

Tags: java, client-server

The process of sending messages to the server seems to be correct, but the server doesn't show the data it got. How can I make it work correctly?

Client's side:

```
void manageClient(){
    try(DatagramChannel datagramChannel = DatagramChannel.open();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)){
        datagramChannel.connect(socketAddress);
          while (true){
            ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(512);
            String r = input.nextLine();
            buf.put(r.getBytes());
            datagramChannel.send(buf, socketAddress);
            messageToSend = null;
            buf.clear();
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Cannot connect to the server!");
    }
}
```

Server's side:

```
    byte[] message = new byte[512];
DatagramPacket datagramPacket = new DatagramPacket(message, message.length);
void manageServer(){
    System.out.println("Waiting for the messages.");
    try(DatagramSocket datagramSocket = new DatagramSocket(7755)){
        try {
            while(true){
                datagramSocket.receive(datagramPacket);
                byte[] tobeString = datagramPacket.getData();
                String q = new String(tobeString, 0, tobeString.length);
                System.out.println("Server got: " + q);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("An error with input.");
        }
    }
    catch(SocketException e){
        System.out.println("A problem with connection occurred!");
    }
}
```

After pressing "Enter" server doesn't show the message it has received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some changes on the client's side were the solution:

```
while (true){
            ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(512);
            r = input.nextLine();
            buf.put(r.getBytes());
            buf.flip();
            datagramChannel.send(buf, socketAddress);
            r = null;
            messageToSend = null;
            buf.clear();
        }
```

I changed the reference to the String and added the `.flip()` method to the buffer.

I hope it will be useful for others who have a similar question.